# Loading spring beans in jar based on application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have a jar say common.jar which contains two cache manager beans like below,

```
@Bean
public CacheManager abcCacheManager() {
  /* Bean for abc service */
}

@Bean
public CacheManager xyzCacheManager() {
  /* Bean for xyz service */
}
```

Both of these beans have different cache names configured as I have two different caches (1 for each application).

Right now when I run abc service, both the cache managers gets activated and loads both caches.

Is there a way I can only trigger particular bean based on the application that is calling?

Comment: trigger bean at Runtime or set some property so when application starts it will contain only beans you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of `@Conditional` annotations group

See 44.3 Condition annotations from [the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

In your case it could be @ConditionalOnClass or @ConditionalOnMissingClass